# Timeout on geolocation get user permission

Tags: javascript, geolocation

I am getting user geolocation with js and want to solve the following scenario:

I have managed to done 1 ~ 4, but having a problem on 5.

The main problem is I can't tell when is the browser starting to get the location.

Thanks

ps: I am using the api at `Geolocation.getCurrentPosition()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition

--- Scenarios ---

1. If user previously chose permission on geo location, give it a 5 seconds timeout on acquiring the location.
2. If user clicks 'deny', return null immediately.
3. If user click 'allow', let browser get geo location with 5 seconds timeout
4. If user ignores the 'allow/deny' prompt, give it a 5 seconds timeout (thinking time) and return null when user still ignore the prompt.
5. If user ignores the 'allow/deny' prompt for within 5 seconds, and clicks 'allow', give the user/browser another 5 seconds for getting the geo location.

--- some code ----

```
api.getGeoLocation = function() {

    var getGeoPromise = $q(function(resolve, reject){

        //give the timeout for user to decided
        var geoPromptTimout = $timeout(function(){
            reject();
        }, GEO_LOCATION_USER_PROMPT_TIMEOUT);

        $window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos){
            $timeout.cancel(geoPromptTimout);
            resolve(pos);
        }, function(positionError) {
            $timeout.cancel(geoPromptTimout);
            reject();
        }, {
            timeout: GEO_LOCATION_ACQUIRE_TIMEOUT,
            maximumAge: GEO_LOCATION_CACHED_AGE
        });
    });

    return getGeoPromise;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I ends up using $q.defer.notify method.

First notify the consume code when it is timeout for user ignoring the prompt.

Then when user click allow just before the timeout, still load geo location in the background, and use notify to tell consume code again geo location successfully acquired.